# Display right click context menu with focus in through VBA macro in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word, contextmenu, office-2007

I would like to programmatically display the right click context menu with focus through a VBA macro in Word 2007.

This would allow me to map the macro to a hotkey and expose the menu with focus without leaving the keyboard. I assumed this would be done through the `Application` object's `CommandBars` collection, accessed along the lines of :

`Application.CommandBars.'access appropriate mehod or member here'`

But I do not see any method or member that seems like it would show the context menu. Is it possible to achieve this through a VBA macro?

**EDIT:**

As suggested I looped through each CommandBar and obtained the name and index to try and find out which CommandBar index to use:

```
Sub C_RightClick()
'Activates right-click context menu
'

Dim cbar As Office.CommandBar
Dim cbarIndex As Integer
Dim testString As String
Dim cBarsArray(0 To 500)
Dim arrayCounter As Integer

testString = ""
arrayCounter = 1

For Each cbar In CommandBars
    'TRUE if right-click
    'If LCase(cbar.Name) = 'right-click' Then
    '    cbarIndex = cbar.Index
    'End If

    testString = testString + CStr(cbar.Index) + " " + cbar.Name + " " + CStr(cbar.Type = msoBarTypePopup) + vbCrLf
    Debug.Print cbar.Name; " "; cbar.Type = msoBarTypePopup

    'Add name to array and increment counter
    cBarsArray(arrayCounter) = cbar.Name
    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1

Next cbar

MsgBox testString

'Application.CommandBars(cbarIndex).ShowPopup


End Sub
```

However, I do not see any titled 'Right-Click'. I thought it may be 'Standard' , whose index is 1, but received an error when I attempted to access it.

If anyone knows the correct name for the default right-click context menu that appears in Word 2007 when the `Home` tab is selected, it would be appreciated. Otherwise, I will take that question to SuperUser and research on my own.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: See my edit for thoughts on the HOME tab menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Application.CommandBars(100).ShowPopup
```

The argument can be the Commandbar index or caption.

To execute a particular command on a commandbar, try something like:

```
Application.CommandBars(100).Controls("Paste").Execute
```

To print a list of all commandbars to the Immediate Window:

```
Sub test()
Dim cbar As Office.CommandBar
For Each cbar In CommandBars
    'TRUE if right-click
    Debug.Print cbar.Name; " "; cbar.Type = msoBarTypePopup
Next cbar
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
In answer to your question about the right-click menu that you get over the HOME tab, I think it's a different kind of control from CommandBar.

To get a better idea of the right-click menu names and indexes, I've modified the code above slightly. This now tries to add a control to each right-click menu. The added control's caption is the menu's name and Index. The controls are temporary - they'll be gone the next time you open Word.

```
Sub test()
Dim cbar As Office.CommandBar
Dim ctl As Office.CommandBarControl
For Each cbar In Application.CommandBars
    With cbar
        On Error Resume Next
        'this will delete any customizations
        .Reset
        Set ctl = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
        ctl.Caption = .Index & " - " & cbar.Name
        Debug.Print "Name: "; cbar.Name; " Right-click: "; cbar.Type = msoBarTypePopup; " Error descr: "; Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next cbar
End Sub
```

It also prints out the error message, if there was one, to the immediate window.

The reason I don't think you'll have luck with the "Home" context menu is that no control is added to it. Here's a pic of a menu with the control added:

[image]